# Under the hood process of the "create shapes from vector layer" option in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm just curious to know what actually happens when After Effects converts an AI file to shapes. I should note that I do have Overlord but sometimes I am working on projects on my university computer and I am unable to load extensions. I find myself working more and more path animation projects but every time import and convert my AI files to shapes I have to manually dive into each shape group and zero out its parameters before animating. I try to set up my projects in AI in a way so it's already the way I need it to be. It would be nice to actually understand how AE handles this process of converting files. Thanks for your help

Comment: No ide of what's going on under the hood, but FYI You can install extensions without admin permission: http://andrewmacfarlane.com/blog/2017/04/how-to-install-after-effects-scripts-extensions-and-plug-ins-without-administrator-access/